# Using an xlam file as an extension for filling in data in other workbooks named cells

Tags: excel, vba, userform

The code i have works, but not as good as i hoped.
I have an .xlam file that i have 2 user forms in. I activate them from the XRibbon with this code.

```
Option Explicit

' Fylla på info i excel filer
Sub StartAnlaggningInformation(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim blnRun As VbMsgBoxResult
Call SafetyCatch("Anläggnings Information", blnRun)
    If blnRun = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
         Call frmProjektInfo.Show
End Sub

' Fylla på info i Schrack beställningsmall
Sub BestSchrackMaterial(control As IRibbonControl)
Dim blnRun As VbMsgBoxResult
Call SafetyCatch("Beställa Scrack-seconet material.", blnRun)
    If blnRun = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Basuppgifter projekt" Then
        Call ValjBestall.Show
    Else
     MsgBox "Välj rätt flik i Schrack's beställningsmall"
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem i have is with the handling of the workbook that is active when i click the button on the ribbon. The code kind of do what i want it to, but i have a feeling that there's a better way to do this that doesn't force the user to only have one excel file open for the code to work:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Run the initialization code here
    InitializeForm
    ' Other code for activation if needed
End Sub

Private Sub InitializeForm()
    ' Populate cbxObjektsnamn with values from column A in DataFile.xlsm
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim objektsnamnRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim headers As Variant

    Dim dataFileName As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Get the path to the user's AppData folder
    Dim appDataPath As String
    appDataPath = Environ("APPDATA")

    ' Set the path to your data Excel file
    dataFileName = appDataPath & "\Microsoft\AddIns\DataFile.xlsm"

    ' Check if the file exists
    If Dir(dataFileName) = "" Then
        ' If the file doesn't exist, create it with headers
        Set wsData = Workbooks.Add.Sheets(1)
        headers = Array("Objektsnamn", "Anläggningsnummer", "Projektnummer", "ProjektledareNamn", "ProjektledareTel", _
                        "DelegeradNamn", "DelegeradTel", "TeknikerNamn", "TeknikerTel", "SBF110", _
                        "Anläggningsägare", "ÄgarAdress", "ÄgarPostnr", "ÄgarPostort", "ObjektAdress", _
                        "ObjektPostort", "ObjektPostnr", "Nyttjare", "AnlSkötare1namn", "AnlSkötare1telefon", _
                        "AnlSkötare2namn", "AnlSkötare2telefon", "LedandeMontörNamn", "LedandeMontörTelefon", _
                        "LevAdress", "LevPostort", "LevPostnr", "LastUsed")

        ' Write headers to the first row
        wsData.Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1).Value = headers

        ' Save the workbook as xlsm
        wsData.Parent.SaveAs dataFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    Else
        ' If the file exists, open it
        Workbooks.Open dataFileName
        Set wsData = Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Sheets(1)
    End If

    ' Assuming DataFile.xlsm is already open
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsData = Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Sheets(1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not wsData Is Nothing Then
        ' Find the last row in column A with data
        lastRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim lastUsedRow As Long
        lastUsedRow = wsData.Range("AB:AB").Find(What:="X", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Row

        If lastRow >= 2 Then ' Check if there is data in the workbook
            ' Set the range for cbxObjektsnamn
            Set objektsnamnRange = wsData.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

            ' Clear the existing items in the ComboBox
            Me.cbxObjektsnamn.Clear

            ' Loop through the range and add each item to the ComboBox
            For Each cell In objektsnamnRange
                Me.cbxObjektsnamn.AddItem cell.Value
            Next cell
            If lastUsedRow >= 2 Then
                Me.cbxObjektsnamn.Text = Me.cbxObjektsnamn.List(lastUsedRow - 2)
            End If
        Else
            ' Handle the case when there is no data in DataFile.xlsm
            MsgBox "Ingen data hittad i fil DataFile.xlsm.", vbExclamation
        End If
    Else
        ' Handle the case when DataFile.xlsm is not open
        MsgBox "DataFile.xlsm är inte öppen.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub cmbCancel_Click()
    ' Close the user form without saving any changes
    Unload Me
    ' Close DataFile.xlsm
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        ' Close DataFile.xlsm
        Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Private Sub cbxObjektsnamn_Change()
    ' Disable the Change event to prevent recursion
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Get the selected value from cbxObjektsnamn
    Dim selectedValue As String
    selectedValue = CStr(Me.cbxObjektsnamn.Value)

    ' Find the corresponding row in DataFile.xlsm based on the selected value
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Sheets(1)

    ' Assuming the data is in columns B to Z (adjust as needed)
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = wsData.Range("A:AA")

    ' Find the row that corresponds to the selected value
    Dim selectedRow As Variant
    selectedRow = Application.Match(selectedValue, dataRange.Columns(1), 0)


    If Not IsError(selectedRow) Then ' Check if a match is found
        ' Update other textboxes with information from the selected row
        Me.tbxAnlaggningsnummer.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 2).Value
        Me.tbxProjektnummer.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 3).Value
        Me.tbxProjektledareNamn.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 4).Value
        Me.tbxProjektledareTel.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 5).Value
        Me.tbxDelegeradNamn.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 6).Value
        Me.tbxDelegeradTel.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 7).Value
        Me.tbxTeknikerNamn.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 8).Value
        Me.tbxTeknikerTel.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 9).Value
        Me.tbxSBF110.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 10).Value
        Me.tbxAnlaggningsagare.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 11).Value
        Me.tbxAgarAdress.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 12).Value
        Me.tbxAgarPostnr.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 13).Value
        Me.tbxAgarPostort.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 14).Value
        Me.tbxObjektAdress.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 15).Value
        Me.tbxObjektPostort.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 16).Value
        Me.tbxObjektPostnr.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 17).Value
        Me.tbxNyttjare.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 18).Value
        Me.tbxAnlSkotare1namn.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 19).Value
        Me.tbxAnlSkotare1telefon.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 20).Value
        Me.tbxAnlSkotare2namn.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 21).Value
        Me.tbxAnlSkotare2telefon.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 22).Value
        Me.tbxLedandeMontorNamn.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 23).Value
        Me.tbxLedandeMontorTelefon.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 24).Value
        Me.tbxLevAdress.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 25).Value
        Me.tbxLevPostort.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 26).Value
        Me.tbxLevPostnr.Value = dataRange.Cells(selectedRow, 27).Value
        
    Else
        ' Handle the case when no match is found
        'MsgBox "No matching data found for " & selectedValue, vbExclamation
    End If

    ' Re-enable the Change event
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Sub UpdateOrAddData()
    ' Get the values from the textboxes on frmProjektInfo
    Dim objektsnamn As String
    Dim Anlaggningsnummer As String
    Dim Projektnummer As String
    Dim ProjektledareNamn As String
    Dim ProjektledareTel As String
    Dim DelegeradNamn As String
    Dim DelegeradTel As String
    Dim TeknikerNamn As String
    Dim TeknikerTel As String
    Dim SBF110 As String
    Dim Anlaggningsagare As String
    Dim AgarAdress As String
    Dim AgarPostnr As String
    Dim AgarPostort As String
    Dim ObjektAdress As String
    Dim ObjektPostor As String
    Dim ObjektPostnr As String
    Dim Nyttjare As String
    Dim AnlSkotare1namn As String
    Dim AnlSkotare1telefon As String
    Dim AnlSkotare2namn As String
    Dim AnlSkotare2telefon As String
    Dim LedandeMontorNamn As String
    Dim LedandeMontorTelefon As String
    Dim LevAdress As String
    Dim LevPostort As String
    Dim LevPostnr As String

    ' Add more variables for other textboxes as needed

    objektsnamn = Me.cbxObjektsnamn.Value
       Anlaggningsnummer = Me.tbxAnlaggningsnummer.Value
       Projektnummer = Me.tbxProjektnummer.Value
       ProjektledareNamn = Me.tbxProjektledareNamn.Value
       ProjektledareTel = Me.tbxProjektledareTel.Value
       DelegeradNamn = Me.tbxDelegeradNamn.Value
       DelegeradTel = Me.tbxDelegeradTel.Value
       TeknikerNamn = Me.tbxTeknikerNamn.Value
       TeknikerTel = Me.tbxTeknikerTel.Value
       SBF110 = Me.tbxSBF110.Value
       Anlaggningsagare = Me.tbxAnlaggningsagare.Value
       AgarAdress = Me.tbxAgarAdress.Value
       AgarPostnr = Me.tbxAgarPostnr.Value
       AgarPostort = Me.tbxAgarPostort.Value
       ObjektAdress = Me.tbxObjektAdress.Value
       ObjektPostor = Me.tbxObjektPostort.Value
       ObjektPostnr = Me.tbxObjektPostnr.Value
       Nyttjare = Me.tbxNyttjare.Value
       AnlSkotare1namn = Me.tbxAnlSkotare1namn.Value
       AnlSkotare1telefon = Me.tbxAnlSkotare1telefon.Value
       AnlSkotare2namn = Me.tbxAnlSkotare2namn.Value
       AnlSkotare2telefon = Me.tbxAnlSkotare2telefon.Value
       LedandeMontorNamn = Me.tbxLedandeMontorNamn.Value
       LedandeMontorTelefon = Me.tbxLedandeMontorTelefon.Value
       LevAdress = Me.tbxLevAdress.Value
       LevPostort = Me.tbxLevPostort.Value
       LevPostnr = Me.tbxLevPostnr.Value
    ' Assign values for other variables as needed
    
    ' Find the corresponding row in DataFile.xlsm based on the objektsnamn value
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Sheets(1)
    wsData.Range("AB2:AB" & wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value = ""
    ' Find or add the row
    Dim targetRow As Long
    targetRow = FindOrAddRow(wsData, objektsnamn)

    ' Update values in the found or added row
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 1).Value = objektsnamn
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 2).Value = Anlaggningsnummer
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 3).Value = Projektnummer
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 4).Value = ProjektledareNamn
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 5).Value = ProjektledareTel
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 6).Value = DelegeradNamn
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 7).Value = DelegeradTel
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 8).Value = TeknikerNamn
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 9).Value = TeknikerTel
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 10).Value = SBF110
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 11).Value = Anlaggningsagare
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 12).Value = AgarAdress
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 13).Value = AgarPostnr
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 14).Value = AgarPostort
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 15).Value = ObjektAdress
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 16).Value = ObjektPostor
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 17).Value = ObjektPostnr
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 18).Value = Nyttjare
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 19).Value = AnlSkotare1namn
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 20).Value = AnlSkotare1telefon
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 21).Value = AnlSkotare2namn
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 22).Value = AnlSkotare2telefon
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 23).Value = LedandeMontorNamn
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 24).Value = LedandeMontorTelefon
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 25).Value = LevAdress
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 26).Value = LevPostort
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 27).Value = LevPostnr
    wsData.Cells(targetRow, 28).Value = "X"
    ' Update other columns as needed
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Save the changes to DataFile.xlsm
    Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Save
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error vid sparande av DataFile.xlsm: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    End If
    On Error Resume Next  ' Reset the error handler

    
End Sub

Private Sub cmbUpDate_Click()

    Dim customRibbonWorkbook As Workbook
    Set customRibbonWorkbook = Workbooks("CustomRibbon.xlam")

    ' Loop through all open workbooks to find the one that is not "CustomRibbon.xlam" or "DataFile.xlsm"
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    For Each targetWorkbook In Workbooks
        If targetWorkbook.Name <> "CustomRibbon.xlam" And targetWorkbook.Name <> "DataFile.xlsm" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next targetWorkbook

    ' Check if a suitable workbook is found
    If targetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        ' Inform the user that no suitable workbook is found
        MsgBox "Ingen lämplig arbetsbok hittades.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Call the procedure to update or add data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    UpdateOrAddData
    InitializeForm
    targetWorkbook.Activate
    
End Sub

Function FindOrAddRow(wsData As Worksheet, objektsnamn As String) As Long
    ' Assuming the data is in columns A to Z (adjust as needed)
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = wsData.Range("A:AA")

    ' Find the row that corresponds to the objektsnamn value
    Dim targetRow As Variant
    targetRow = Application.Match(objektsnamn, dataRange.Columns(1), 0)

    If Not IsError(targetRow) Then ' Check if a match is found
        ' If a match is found, return the matching row
        FindOrAddRow = CLng(targetRow)
    Else
        ' If no match is found, find the last empty row in column A
        FindOrAddRow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
End Function

Private Sub cmbOK_Click()
    ' Call the procedure to update or add data
    UpdateOrAddData
    ' Fill named cells in the active workbook
    FillNamedCells
    ' Close the user form
    Unload Me
    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub FillNamedCells()
    ' Get the workbook where the VBA code is running (ThisWorkbook)
    Dim customRibbonWorkbook As Workbook
    Set customRibbonWorkbook = Workbooks("CustomRibbon.xlam")

    ' Loop through all open workbooks to find the one that is not "CustomRibbon.xlam" or "DataFile.xlsm"
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    For Each targetWorkbook In Workbooks
        If targetWorkbook.Name <> "CustomRibbon.xlam" And targetWorkbook.Name <> "DataFile.xlsm" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next targetWorkbook

    ' Check if a suitable workbook is found
    If targetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        ' Inform the user that no suitable workbook is found
        MsgBox "Ingen lämplig arbetsbok hittades.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Use the values from the user form to fill named cells
    On Error Resume Next
    targetWorkbook.Names("Objektsnamn").RefersToRange.Value = Me.cbxObjektsnamn.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("Anlaggningsnummer").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxAnlaggningsnummer.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("Projektnummer").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxProjektnummer.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("Projektledare").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxProjektledareNamn.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("ProjektledareTel").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxProjektledareTel.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("DelegeradNamn").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxDelegeradNamn.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("DelegeradTel").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxDelegeradTel.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("TeknikerNamn").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxTeknikerNamn.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("TeknikerTel").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxTeknikerTel.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("SBF110").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxSBF110.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("Anlaggningsagare").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxAnlaggningsagare.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("AgarAdress").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxAgarAdress.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("AgarPostnr").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxAgarPostnr.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("AgarPostort").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxAgarPostort.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("ObjektAdress").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxObjektAdress.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("ObjektPostor").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxObjektPostort.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("ObjektPostnr").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxObjektPostnr.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("Nyttjare").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxNyttjare.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("AnlSkotare1namn").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxAnlSkotare1namn.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("AnlSkotare1telefon").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxAnlSkotare1telefon.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("AnlSkotare2namn").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxAnlSkotare2namn.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("AnlSkotare2telefon").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxAnlSkotare2telefon.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("LedandeMontor").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxLedandeMontorNamn.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("LedandeMontorTelefon").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxLedandeMontorTelefon.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("LevAdress").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxLevAdress.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("LevPostort").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxLevPostort.Value
    targetWorkbook.Names("LevPostnr").RefersToRange.Value = Me.tbxLevPostnr.Value
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Save the changes to the target workbook
    targetWorkbook.Save

    ' Inform the user about the successful operation
    MsgBox "Namngivna celler har uppdaterats i " & targetWorkbook.Name, vbInformation
End Sub


Private Sub cmbTaBort_Click()
    ' Get the selected value from cbxObjektsnamn
    Dim selectedValue As String
    selectedValue = CStr(Me.cbxObjektsnamn.Value)

    ' Find the corresponding row in DataFile.xlsm based on the selected value
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Set wsData = Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Sheets(1)

    ' Assuming the data is in columns B to Z (adjust as needed)
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = wsData.Range("A:Z")

    ' Find the row that corresponds to the selected value
    Dim selectedRow As Variant
    selectedRow = Application.Match(selectedValue, dataRange.Columns(1), 0)

    If Not IsError(selectedRow) Then ' Check if a match is found
        ' Confirm with the user before removing the row
        Dim confirmation As VbMsgBoxResult
        confirmation = MsgBox("Är du säker på att du vill ta bort data för " & selectedValue & "?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Tabort Data")

        If confirmation = vbYes Then
            ' Remove the row
            wsData.Rows(selectedRow).Delete

            ' Save changes to "DataFile.xlsm"
            Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Save

            ' Close "DataFile.xlsm"
            Workbooks("DataFile.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

            ' Inform the user that the row has been removed
            MsgBox "Data för " & selectedValue & " har tagits bort.", vbInformation

            ' Unload the user form
            Unload Me
        End If
    Else
        ' Handle the case when no match is found
        MsgBox "Inga matchande data hittades för " & selectedValue, vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmbHelp_Click()
 MsgBox "För att få hjälp med hur detta formulär fungerar se filen Personlig Vertygslist Information.dox som finns under mappen J:\EL\Säkerhet\Anläggarfirma Brandlarm\Mallar\Excel\Personlig verktygslist" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "CustomRibbon.xlam" & vbCrLf & "Version 1.0", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion, "Hjälp"
End Sub
```

The .xlam file i saved in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns. This code/function is going to be used by several different people and needs to be easy installed. Even just adding this .xlam file to Excel addins is a bit hard for some users.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you try doing and what problem you have... An add-in can be provided with a piece of code to make it self-installable when you open if for the first time. Why do you try saving the add-in as xlsm?

Comment: I actually think I found the "problem" you have. Is it the loop workbook thing in `cmbUpDate_Click`? Can't you use ActiveWorkBook? Or is there nothing in a workbook that is defined. Like A1 should always be "some text", or there should be a date somewhere, or lines at some specific cells?

Comment: FaneDuru I'm not saving the add-in as xlsm it's a xlam file. The xlsm file is for data storage.

The problem i have is when i'm using frmProjektInfo. If i have more the one workbook open the program has a hard time to figurer out witch of the workbook's was active when i activated frmProjektInfo so the data gets transferred the the right workbook.

Comment: Andreas No i can't get ActiveWorkbook to work correctly, it doesn't ad the data to the workbook that was active when i activated frmProjektInfo.

Comment: @Mirkaminer That is probably because your code change what is the active workbook somewhere. What you can do is to "save" the active workbook as a variable and use that in your code. I would suggest you dim the variable as public then  `set Awb = activeworkbook` in cmbUpDate_Click as an example. When the code later needs to write to the "activeworkbook" you write `Awb.sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value = "Hello"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not either sure what your issue is when you say *"but i have a feeling that there's a better way to do this that doesn't force the user to only have one excel file open for the code to work"*

But the other issue, to install an xlam can be done with a self installing code.
This only installs if no other workbooks are open. Make sure the users don't open the file from and email, they need to open it from a path or save it on the desktop then open it.
I'll just leave my Swedish comments in there since you are Swedish too.

```
#If VBA7 Then
   Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
      (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
      ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
      ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long
#Else
   Private Declare Function apiCopyFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" _
      (ByVal lpExistingFileName As String, _
      ByVal lpNewFileName As String, _
      ByVal bFailIfExists As Long) As Long
#End If


Private Sub Workbook_open()
    ' Är makrot inte installerat
    If Dir(Application.UserLibraryPath & "Your_file.xlam") = "" And Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
        answer = MsgBox("Installera Your_file makro?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Installera makro?")
        If answer = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub ' installera inte
        Else
            ' kopiera filen som öppnades till add-in mappen
            Result = apiCopyFile(ThisWorkbook.FullName, Application.UserLibraryPath & "Your_file.xlam", False)
            AddIns("Your_file").Installed = True ' Aktivera makrot
            If Result = 1 Then
                ' Avsluta Excel
                On Error Resume Next
                Application.Interactive = False
                AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
                Application.Quit
                Exit Sub 'Om inte stäng av fungerar avsluta makrot
            End If
        End If
    End If
End sub
```

If you want to remotely be able to send updates to the users then you can add a code that checks for updates and asks the user if he/she wants to update.
This is also part of `Workbook_open()`. paste it below the last `end if`

```
pth = "X:\SomePathEveryoneHasAccessTo\" 
' kolla efter uppdateringar
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(pth & "version.txt", 1)
Ver = CInt(objFile.ReadLine)
objFile.Close


' kolla efter uppdateringar
If Ver > 1 Then
    ans = MsgBox("Ny version finns tillgänglig av Your_file makro." & vbCr & "Vill du uppdatera?", vbYesNo)
End If
If ans = vbYes Then
    MsgBox ("Excel kommer stängas efter uppdateringen och du får öppna filen igen manuellt." & vbCr & "Uppdateringen är klar när den svarta rutan stängs automatiskt.")
    Dim xWB As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xWB In Application.Workbooks
        If Not (xWB Is Application.ActiveWorkbook) Then
            xWB.Close
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MyFile = Environ("Temp") & "\Temp.bat"
    fnum = FreeFile()
    Open MyFile For Output As #fnum
    If Application.OperatingSystem = "Windows (32-bit) NT 5.01" Then
        Print #fnum, "ping -n 3 127.0.0.1>nul"
    Else
        Print #fnum, "timeout /T 3 >nul"
    End If
    Print #fnum, "copy /Y " & Chr(34) & pth & "Your_file.xlam" & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Application.UserLibraryPath & "Your_file.xlam" & Chr(34)
    Close #fnum
    
    Shell MyFile, vbNormalFocus
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.Interactive = False
    AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
    Application.Quit
    Exit Sub
End If
```

On line 10 in the code block above you see `If Ver > 1 Then`, here you need to change the `1` to whatever version of the macro you are sending out to the users.
Preferably you increase the number with 1 each time.
Save the xlam, and then copy the file to "X:\SomePathEveryoneHasAccessTo".
Then when all that is done, you can open the version.txt file in the same path and change it to the same version as you have in the macro code.

So what will happen is that when a user opens Excel, the workbook open code checks if it's the latest version from the version.txt file.
And it's not, so the code asks if it you want to update.

If yes then a temporary file is created with batch code that copies the xlam to the users xlam folder.
This code runs with a delay (timeout/ping part of the code), during this delay Excel  closes itself to make sure the xlam can be overwritten.

Comment: Didn't even think of adding an automatic update to the add-in. This worked great. Thanks